# creating a hashmap for a particular condition in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to create a hashmap of:

```
{Integer, List<Integer>}.
```

For example, I have the following set:
Numbers {
0,1,3,4,5
0,1,4,5,6
0,1,6,7,8
1,2,5,6,7
1,2,4,5,6 }

I need to create a hashmap with the first value in the above set as key while adding the values into lists like so:
hashmap = [0 = {1,3,4,5}, {1,4,5,6}, {1,6,7,8}]
          [1 = {2,5,6,7}, {2,4,5,6}]

and so on.

I traverse the set. If the first value is different from the previous, I need to create a new list and start storing. Otherwise I need to add values to the previously created list.

I am having trouble creating the new list. 
If I do something like this:

```
    int prev = 0;
    for(Number n : Numbers)
    {
        int current = n;
        if(prev_first != current)
        {
            List<Integer> l = new Arraylist<>();
            hashmap.out(current, l);
            l.add(n);
        }
        else
        {
            l.add(n);
        }
    }
```

The trouble is the compiler cannot see the list 'l' and says that it may not be initialised for the else condition.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks and regards,
Smitha.

Comment: Move `List<Integer> l = new Arraylist<>();` out of the `if` statement.

Comment: Don't you need a `Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>>`?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the list in the `if` statement. Therefore you cannot access the list from the `else` statement. Just create the list before the `if` statement and the compiler will stop complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `l` only exists in the `if`-Condition. `else` does not see it.
Try:

```
int prev = 0;
for(Number n : Numbers)
{
    int current = n;
    List<Integer> l = new Arraylist<>();
    if(prev_first != current)
    {            
        hashmap.out(current, l);
        l.add(n);
    }
    else
    {
        l.add(n);
    }
}
```